# How to add custom filter of undertow by using jboss.cli

Tags: jboss, servlet-filters, undertow

Server : WindFly 15, Undertow 8

I've created a custom filter "MyFilter" by following the article http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web/jbosswebserver/configuring-undertow-filters-on-wildfly. But i didn't find the way to use jboss.cli to add it in the configuration.

I've tried /subsystem=undertow/configuration=filter/filter=myFilter/:add(module=com.xxx.myfilter,class-name=com.xxx.MyFilter), and got the following error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.cli.CommandContext] Failed to get the list of the operationproperties: "WFLYCTL0030: No resource definition is registered for address [
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("configuration" => "filter"),
    ("filter" => "myFilter")
```

So whether we can only add filter by manually editing the configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

you can add using the cli with the following command:

```
/subsystem=undertow/configuration=filter/custom-filter
```

The original answer can be found [here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/280706).

---

This is related to the custom filter creation explained on the [Guide Configuring The Web Server ~ Undertow - Chapter 17.6](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuration_guide/configuring_the_web_server_undertow)

```
/subsystem=undertow/configuration=filter/response-header=new-response-header:add(header-name=new-response-header,header-value="My Value")
```

### Tip

The main tip is to use the `Tab` so then the auto complete comes to you.